# Is there a motive attached to half weight modular forms?

Tags: modular-forms, motives

The question is kind of contained in the title but let me add a few words.

If $f$ is a cusp form of weight $k$ for $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ then Scholl constructed a Grothendieck motive $M(f)$. In this case $k$ is an even natural number.

What happens for modular forms of half weight? Is there some motivic construction attached to them? I would be particularly interested in the case of the $\eta$ function.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm far from an expert but it seems very ambitious to ask for a motive, I don't think it's even clear what the correct notion of an attached Galois representation or $L$-function is in this context. What properties do you want from this motive? Try googling "l-function attached to modular form of half integral weight" and you'll find lots of places to start reading.

Comment: I'd agree with Dan that this is essentially the same question as "do L-functions exist for half-integral weight modular forms". This was asked before, and got a *very* nice answer from Marty Weissman: [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/113811/do-l-functions-exist-for-half-integral-weight-modular-forms]